# ggplot2 same set of colors to different groups

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, grouping, tidyverse

I'm using `tidyverse`.

I got this data for example
https://pastebin.com/uvCqVMFp

And I'd like grouping the lines by the columns 'regiao' and 'estado'.
Then I change the aesthetics to change the `linetype` per 'regiao' and the `color` per 'estado'

```
data %>% 
  filter( estado != "BR") %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_path(aes(data, log(casosAcumulados), group = estado, color = estado, linetype = regiao)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 1))
```

Then I got this:

[image]

But the colors still confusing.

So, I'd like to allow 1 unique set of colors to each 'regiao'. 
Since there is no more than 9 'estates' per 'region' (number max of unique values) `data %>%  group_by(regiao) %>%  summarise(num = n_distinct(estado))` I want at maximum os 9 colors (as different as it can).
Otherwise, I'm open to suggestions about another way to turn it more clear to visualization.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to create a named vector listing the levels of `regiao` and indicate what colours you want to each. Something like `c("estado1" = "#FFA07A", etc...)` and then add `scale_colour_manual(values = colour_vec)` or whatever you named that vector.

Comment: @Phil thanks. I was thinking of something a little more automatic.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://github.com/poissonconsulting/tinter Note that it was removed from CRAN in February, but you can still download the GH version.

Comment: Your plot is too crowded. You might want to consider some suggestions in these post https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Ten-Simple-Rules-for-Better-Figures-Rougier-Droettboom/e6fe556713b8f19977609a0ff29500fff302befc

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126480/color-and-line-thickness-recommendations-for-line-plots?stw=2 & https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118033/best-series-of-colors-to-use-for-differentiating-series-in-publication-quality?stw=2

Comment: I also thought in use `facet_wrap( . ~ regiao,  ncol = 3)`

Comment: I second the suggestion to use `facet_wrap`.